# Can't configure AirPort Extreme - device won't save settings changed from defaults

Tags: airport-extreme

I have factory reset my AirPort Extreme (Model A1521) and I am trying to configure it to replace a TP-Link router that seems to have issues when multiple devices are using the Wi-Fi (it drops the Wi-Fi making streaming impossible).

If I accept the default settings (Wi-Fi name, device name etc.) then it successfully configures and I get on the Internet.

However, if I then try and change the Wi-Fi name to the name I want (as configured on the TP-Link router) then it gives me an error message saying updating the settings failed.

The router LED goes Green for a few seconds and then flashes Orange. Whilst Green it appears in AirPort Utility but disappears when it goes to the flashing Orange state. The only way to do anything with it after this is to reset it back to factory.

I am connected to the APE via a network cable from my MBP.

I've tried this several times, reducing what I change from the defaults to a minimum. If I use a different Wi-Fi name (I suffix '2' to the end) then it works. Am I doing something wrong? Firmware is up-to-date on the APE.

Comment: Which network mode are you putting the AirPort Extreme into? You can't use "Extend a Network" when the existing network is published by a third-party router (this mode is *wireless* extension of the existing network, and is only an AirPort-to-AirPort thing). You need to use "Create a Network".

Comment: I disconnect the power to my existing router and then do "Create a Network" as you say. I have it working in bridging mode currently, but I need to get rid of the other router.